# Seeding files from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webtorrent

I'm trying to allow a user to select a file from their computer and start seeding it, I've followed the example [here](https://webtorrent.io/intro). I've used a normal input rather than using drag and drop as I couldn't get it to work.

Now whenever a file is selected I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: filesystem paths do not work in the browser

How can I start seeding from a user's computer without uploading the file to my server?

Comment: Not sure, I guess I could use some sort of ajax. What are you suggesting?

Comment: Em i'm new to web dev too lol,but i do know how to sending file by using PHP,because two of my projects is powered by PHP,if you got interested i can leave an answer down below.

Comment: The user can select a file from their machine and upload it to a web server, which could then make it available to others, but I don't think you can seed a file in a strict P2P sense.

Comment: @ManoDestra Using the open source WebTorrent you can create p2p connections in the browser via javascript & WebRTC sockets :)

Comment: @KieranCrown Directly peer to peer, without a server? Nice. Need to look into that. Know of any good articles on the topic?

Comment: @ManoDestra Just visit the WebTorrent home page they have examples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you tryed reading a file with `file:///`, but this not possible for security reasons. A file must be selected or drap&droped from the user.
The simplest solution is with a button:

```js
function readFile(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0]
  if (!file) {
    return
  }
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = evt => {
    var contents = evt.target.result
    console.log(contents)
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="readFile.call(this, event)" />
```

With this snippet you can read a file without any interaction with a server and thats ideal for a serverless techlology like torrent.

Comment: I tested your code, it successfully outputs the contents of the file however it freezes the browser when doing so, I need the system path of the file so I can start seeding the file

Comment: Yes if you use a bigger file it will freeze, but thats only because of the `console.log`. If you only safe it in a variable it will be fine. To the second part: You will never get access to the files directly! But in the docs is this `client.seed(files, callback)`, with that should can easily use the `evt.target.files` direcly, or only one file, like in the example.